# Cross Browser Pure CSS3 Vertical Accordion - Keep window open until another window is clicked

Tags: css, menu, accordion

How do I edit the code so that the window will stay open even when the mouse is no longer hovering, but will close when another window/category is selected?

```
.verticalaccordion>ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style:none;
    width: 500px;
}

.verticalaccordion>ul>li {
    display:block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style:none;
    height:40px;
    width: 500px;

    /* Decorative CSS */
    background-color:#f0f0f0;

    /* CSS3 Transition Effect */
    transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.verticalaccordion>ul>li>h3 {
    display:block;
    margin: 0;
    padding:10px;
    height:19px;

    /* Decorative CSS */
    border-top:#f0f0f0 1px solid;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color: #000;
    background: #cccccc;

    /* CSS3 Gradient Effect */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( top, #999999, #cccccc);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#999999), to(#cccccc));
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ff999999, endColorstr=#ffcccccc); /* IE 7 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ff999999, endColorstr=#ffcccccc)";   /* IE 8 */
}

.verticalaccordion>ul>li>div {
    margin:0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding:10px;
    height:220px;
}

.verticalaccordion>ul>li:hover {
    height: 280px;
}

.verticalaccordion:hover>ul>li:hover>h3 {
    /* Decorative CSS */
    color:#fff;
    background: #000000;

    /* CSS3 Gradient Effect */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( top, #454545, #000000); /* FF, Flock */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#454545), to(#000000)); /* Safari, Chrome */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ff454545, endColorstr=#ff000000); /* IE 5.5 - IE 7 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ff454545, endColorstr=#ff000000)";   /* IE 8 */
}

.verticalaccordion>ul>li>h3:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}

    <div class="verticalaccordion">
<ul>
    <li>
        <h3>Heading 1</h3>
        <div>Content For Panel 1.</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>Heading 2</h3>
        <div>Content For Panel 2</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>Heading 3</h3>
        <div>Content For Panel 3.</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>Heading 4</h3>
        <div>Content For Panel 4</div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here is the source for the above code: [Cross Browser Pure CSS3 Vertical Accordion](http://www.w3avenue.com/2010/04/02/cross-browser-pure-css3-vertical-accordion/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't know in pure CSS what happens to an element placed after the current one (or to its children). So even with `:target + li > a:hover`, `:focus ~ blah` or whatever you could make up, you won't know what to do to the first link when something happens to the third one.

Use jQuery (or JS or any framework) for complex menus, it's more usable with better compatibility with not so old browsers ;)